# WPF expander not expanded above buttons make buttons unclickable

Tags: wpf, xaml, clickable, expander

In a WPF form, I have an expander that expands above other controls, such as buttons :

```
<Expander Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="99" Name="searchMenuExpander" Header="Search menu" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,0,0" MinWidth="510" MinHeight="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="MidnightBlue" Cursor="Arrow">
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <TextBlock Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,10,0,0" Width="65" Height="20" Cursor="Arrow" />
        <TextBox Name="nameSearchTextBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="115,10,0,0" Width="100" Height="20"/>
    </Grid>
</Expander>
<Button Content="Button" Height="34" Width="85"/>
```

My problem is that my controls that are behind the expander are not clickable anymore, even when the expander is not expanded. What is happening? How could I get rid of this bug?

Comment: What is the parent control that wraps your `Expander`?

Comment: What is the purpose of the canvas-positioning for the Button?

Comment: The parent control is just a grid. Forget the canvas, it's part of a bigger code but it does not matter here. I edited my question to remove it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way of doing it, with code behind. I put my `Expander` in a `Canvas` and I added to my `Expander` two events:

`Expanded="searchMenuExpander_Expanded"` and `Collapsed="searchMenuExpander_Collapsed"`
which are defined as:

```
    private void searchMenuExpander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas.SetZIndex(searchMenuCanvas, 99);
    }

    private void searchMenuExpander_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas.SetZIndex(searchMenuCanvas, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Grid` that is the parent of both your `Expander` and your `Button`, you need to put the Button on a different row.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander Grid.Row="0">
    </Expander>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

By setting the `Height` of the first row (which contains the expander) to `Auto`, you ensure that it will be minimized when the expander is not-expanded (only the header part of the expander will occupy space).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but unfortunately this does not work. If I set its height to Auto, the bug is still happening. If I set it to an integer value, it works, but by moving down the button. I'd like to just make the expander expands above the button.

Comment: The problem is with using a canvas to position the button, it overrides any container logic (such as grid rows/columns).